# Infix to Postfix using a stack w/Regex

Tags: python-3.x, stack, postfix-notation

I'm trying to figure out a homework assignment and I've run into a very specific weird problem. Basically I'm using regex to pull all of the operators and operands out one at a time in order of operations, and then pop them off a stack while printing them in the correct postfix notation. It works in most cases, however when running the unittest it fails test_infix14, test_infix_bad_expression, and test bad postfix. I can tell that it's something to do with the way + and - is coming out of the expression (I think) but I have no idea what's making it do it this way. Any help is appreciated. I thought I had this one good and done on Friday but this one little issue has occupied 2 whole days :P

```
''' Main Driver Code '''
import re
import stack

def eval_postfix(postfix):
    ''' Postfix '''
    stac = stack.Stack()
    tokens = re.findall(r'\d+|\+|\-|\*|\/', postfix)
    if len(tokens) == 0:
        raise ValueError
    if len(tokens) < 2:
        return float(tokens[0])
    for toke in tokens:
        if toke.isnumeric():
            stac.push(float(toke))
        else: # t is an operator
            op1 = stac.pop() #operand 1
            op2 = stac.pop() #operand 2
            if toke == '+':
                result = op2 + op1
            elif toke == '-':
                result = op2 - op1
            elif toke == '*':
                result = op2 * op1
            elif toke == '/':
                result = op2 / op1
            stac.push(result)
    return float(stac.pop())

def precedence(top, inputSymbol): # check if top has >= precedence than inputSymbol
    ''' Helper precedence function '''
    if len(re.findall(r'\(|\)|\-|\+|\*|\/', top)) > 0: # if top of stack is an operator
        prec = ['(', '-', '+', '*', '/', ')'] # ascending precedence
        topPrec = prec.index(top)  #e.g.: top == '+', then topPrec == 1
        symbol_input = prec.index(inputSymbol)
        #e.g.: inputSymbol == '/', then symbol_input == 4
        return topPrec >= symbol_input #e.g.: 1 >= 4:  false
    return False

def in2post(infix):
    result = ""
    if infix == [None]:
        raise ValueError
    tokens = re.findall(r'\d+|\(|\)|\+|\-|\*|\/', infix)
    stac = stack.Stack()
    for t in tokens:
        if t == '(':
            stac.push(t)
        elif t.isnumeric():
            result += t + ' '
        elif len(re.findall(r'\+|\-|\*|\/', t)) > 0:
            while stac.size() > 0 and precedence(stac.peek(), t): #and s.peek() != '('
                result += stac.pop() + ' '
            stac.push(t)
        else:
            result += stac.pop() + ' '
            while stac.peek() != '(':
                result += stac.pop() + ' '
            stac.pop()
    while stac.size() > 0:
        if stac.peek() != '(':
            result += stac.pop() + ' '
    return result

def main():
    ''' Main Function '''
    with open("data.txt") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            print("infix: %s" % line, end='')
            postfix = in2post(line)
            print("postfix: %s" % postfix)
            answer = eval_postfix(postfix)
            print("answer: %s" % answer)
            print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
''' stack class '''
class Stack:
    ''' see above doc string '''
    def __init__(self):
        ''' constructor '''
        self.stack_array = []

    def push(self, item):
        ''' add to the stack '''
        self.stack_array.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        ''' remove from the array '''
        #try:
        #    return self.stack_array.pop()
        #except IndexError:
        #    print(self.stack_array)
        if len(self.stack_array) == 0:
            raise IndexError
        return self.stack_array.pop()

    def peek(self):
        ''' See top item of array '''
        #if self.stack_array == [')']:
        #    raise SyntaxError
        if len(self.stack_array) == 0:
            raise IndexError
        return self.stack_array[-1]

    def size(self):
        ''' get total size of array '''
        return len(self.stack_array)

    def clear(self):
        ''' clear whole array '''
        self.stack_array = []
```

```
import unittest
from stack import Stack
from main import eval_postfix as epf
from main import in2post as i2p
from main import main as mn
import io
import sys

class TestEvaluation(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bad_postfix(self):
        self.assertRaises(SyntaxError,  epf, " 7 9 * 7 + 5 6 * - 3 + 4 -+")
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, epf, [None])

class TestIn2Postfix(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_infix_14(self):
        postfix = i2p("7*9+7-5*6+3-4")
        self.assertEqual(postfix.replace(" ", ""), "7 9 * 7 + 5 6 * - 3 + 4 -".replace(" ", ""))
    def test_infix_bad_expression(self):
        self.assertRaises(SyntaxError, i2p, "(8+3)*(5-6))")

class TestMainOutput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main_output(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        captured_output = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = captured_output
        mn()
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        data = "".join(captured_output.getvalue().split())
        print(sys.stdout)
        data1 = "infix: 4postfix:  4answer: 4.0infix: 5  +7postfix:  5 7 +answer: 12.0infix: 7*5postfix:  7 5 *answer: 35.0infix: (5-3)postfix:  5 3 -answer: 2.0infix: 5/5postfix:  5 5 /answer: 1.0infix: 8*5+3postfix:  8 5 * 3 +answer: 43.0infix: 8*(5+3)postfix:  8 5 3 + *answer: 64.0infix: 8+3*5-7postfix:  8 3 5 * + 7 -answer: 16.0infix: (8+3)*(5-6)postfix:  8 3 + 5 6 - *answer: -11.0infix: ((8+3)*(2-7))postfix:  8 3 + 2 7 - *answer: -55.0infix: ((8+3)*2)-7postfix:  8 3 + 2 * 7 -answer: 15.0infix: (8*5)+((3-2)-7*3)postfix:  8 5 * 3 2 - 7 3 * - +answer: 20.0infix: ((8*5+3)-7)-(5*3)postfix:  8 5 * 3 + 7 - 5 3 * -answer: 21.0infix: 7*9+7-5*6+3-4postfix:  7 9 * 7 + 5 6 * - 3 + 4 -answer: 39.0".replace(" ","")
        self.assertEqual(data, data1)
```

Comment: Correct Output: 79*7+56*-3+4- Answer 33
My Output:        79*7+56*3+-4- Answer 33

Comment: You could trim the posted code to just those test cases you *are* asking about.

Comment: That's fair I just didn't want to leave any context out. Let me see if I can trim it up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `precedence` function. The rules for the [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail) say:

```
if the token is an operator, then:
    while ((there is a function at the top of the operator stack)
           or (there is an operator at the top of the operator stack with greater precedence)
           or (the operator at the top of the operator stack has equal precedence and the token is left associative))
          and (the operator at the top of the operator stack is not a left parenthesis):
        pop operators from the operator stack onto the output queue.
    push it onto the operator stack.
```

Addition and subtraction (`+` and `-`) have equal precedence, and multiplication and division (`*` and `/`) have equal precedence. But your `precedence` function gives `+` higher precedence than `-`, and `*` higher than `/`. That will give the wrong output.

For example, if you're given the infix expression `7-3+4`, then after parsing the `3`, your output is `7 3`, and the stack contains `-`. You parse the `+` and you see that `+` has higher precedence than `-`, so you push it onto the operator stack. Then you parse `4` and end up with output of `7 3 4`. Finally, you start popping the stack, ending up with `7 3 4 + 1`. Which will evaluate as `7 - (3 + 4)`.

You have to change your precedence function so that `-` and `+` have the same precedence. And `*` and `/` have the same precedence.

Comment: wow this is a fantastic answer thank you. I ended up figuring it out and haven't been on SO since, but after seeing this I revisited my code and I see what you're saying. Thank you@